# How to show that $ln \ Y$ of uniform distributed random variable is exponential distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

We have a random variable called $U$

$U \sim unif[0,1]$

$Y:=1/U^{1/3}$

Then I had to determine CDF, PDF and mean which are the following

(i) CDF

$F_{Y}(b)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b^3}\ \  \ b \in[0,1] \\
0 \ \ \ \  \ b<0\\
1 \ \ \ \  \ b>1
\end{cases}$

(ii) PDF

$f(b)=F'(B)=\begin{cases}
-3b^{-4}\  \ \ \ b\in[0,1] \\
0  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{else}
\end{cases}$

(iii) mean

$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[1/U^{1/3}]=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^{1/3}}\cdot \frac{1}{1} \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(u) du=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u^{1/3}} du=\left[\frac{3}{2}u^{2/3}\right]_0^1=\frac{3}{2}$

Now I have to show that $ln \ Y$ is exponential distributed with a parameter $\lambda$. But I don't how the approach for this problem looks like.

Comment: Check your answer in part i) CDF. A CDF has to be non-decreasing, so that the corresponding pdf has to be non-negative. Have you learn how to find the CDF/pdf of a random variable after a $1-1$ transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple given you have derived the distribution of $Y$, but you have not done this correctly, the negative PDF should have been a tip off...

First, let's get the CDF of $Y$:

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y \le y)\\
& = P(U^{-1/3} \le y)\\
& = P(U^{1/3} \ge \frac{1}{y})\\
& = P(U \ge y^{-3})\\
& = 1- P(U \le y^{-3})\\
& = 1-F_U(y^{-3})\\
& = 1 - y^{-3}
\end{align*}

Therefore, the pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y) = 3y^{-2}$

Now, let $Z = lnY$, then:

\begin{align*}
F_Z(z) & = P(Z \le z) \\ 
& = P(lnY \le z)\\
& = P(Y \le e^z)\\
&= F_Y(e^z)\\
& = 1 - (e^z)^{-3}\\
& = 1-e^{-3z}
\end{align*}

and so the pdf of $Z$ is:

$$
f_Z(z) = 3e^{-3 z}, \quad z > 0
$$

therefore, $Z \sim \text{expo}(\lambda =3)$ and so $E(Z) = \lambda^{-1} = 1/3$